# A button and a key trying to execute both a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, binding

I have this program where in order to input the information you can press the "button 1" Ingresa or just pressing Enter.
The problem that i'm having is that in order to bind the key "" to the function "cantidad_items" i have to adress an event thtat breaks the button1.
How can i solve this so both options are viable?

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import webbrowser

#cantidad de items (el event activa el Enter)
def cantidad_items(event):
    
    global x
    
    x= int(texto1.get())
    texto1.delete(0, END)
    
    texto1.bind("<Return>",añadir)
    label1.configure(text = "Ingrese el título de los ítems")
    boton1.configure(text = "Ingresar", command=añadir)
    
#nombre de los items e impresión
def añadir(event = None): #No entiendo, explicación: bind() runs with argument, command= runs without argument

    new=2
    tabUrl = "http://google.com/?#q="
    item = texto1.get()
    lista.append(item)
    texto1.delete(0, END)
    
    if len(lista)== x:
        texto1.destroy()
        boton1.destroy()
        label1.destroy()
        rando = random.choice(lista)
        if ("coger" in lista):
            resultado = Label(window, text="Toca coger", font= "Helvetica 30")
            resultado.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor= CENTER)
        elif ("Coger" in lista):
            resultado = Label(window, text="Toca coger", font= "Helvetica 30")
            resultado.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor= CENTER)
        else:
            webbrowser.open(tabUrl + rando, new=new)

            
## Revisar bug con ingresar()----------------------

#main -------------------------------------------------------------------

x = 0
lista = []

#generación de ventana
window = Tk()

window.title("Decidir que mierda hacer con Mora")
window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure(background="light blue")

#descripciones
label1 = Label(window, text="Introduzca la cantidad de ítems",font="Helvetica 16", bd="3", background="light grey")
label1.place(relx = 0.5, rely= 0.35, anchor=CENTER)

#primer entry del número
texto1 = Entry(window, font = "Helvetica 17", width = 26)
texto1.bind("<Return>", cantidad_items)
texto1.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)

#firma
firma = Label(window, text="HermesBV",font = "Times 10", background= "light blue")
firma.place(relx = 1, rely= 1, anchor=SE)

#botón ejecución del input
boton1 = Button(window, text = "Ingresar", command = cantidad_items)
boton1.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.55, anchor= CENTER)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `event` parameter optional:

```
def cantidad_items(event=None):
    ...
```

As long as the function doesn't actually need the `event` object to function properly, you can now use the function both in a binding and as the value of a `command` option.

```
texto1.bind("<Return>", cantidad_items)
boton1 = Button(..., command = cantidad_items)
```